# What is the syntax for storing a specific class's member functions in a vector?

Tags: c++

I did quite a bit of searching, but the combination of * () and class scope has greatly hindered me in understanding of the syntax, with each edit throwing a new error, any help guys?

What I'm trying to do:

Declare a std::vector of pointers to member functions found in MyClass.h

Assign the actual member functions to the std::vector in MyClass.cpp's constructor

The member functions are not static

Thanks!

Comment: Do these functions all have the same signature?

Comment: @chris

Yes, right now they are all in the same class and all take no parameters but they are differently named, I'm not sure if the names are considered part of the signature or not =s

Comment: Nope, just the types and some modifiers.

Comment: @chris
Yup, they're all the same then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm curious where you're going to use them from. You see in order to call a C++ class member function you need to have an instance pointer with which to call it (each member function needs a this in order to access the class state). So normally you'd wrap the member function pointer together with the instance pointer with std::bind and then maybe store the result in std::function. To put them in vector they're all going to need the same signature.

Is this the kind of thing you were looking for:

```
class P
{
    typedef std::function<void (void)> func_t;
    std::vector<func_t> functions;
public:
    P()
    {
        functions.push_back(std::bind(&P::foo1, this));
        functions.push_back(std::bind(&P::foo2, this));
        functions.push_back(std::bind(&P::foo3, this));
    }
    void foo1(void)
    {
        std::cout << "foo1\n";
    }
    void foo2(void)
    {
        std::cout << "foo2\n";
    }
    void foo3(void)
    {
        std::cout << "foo3\n";
    }
    void call()
    {
        for(auto it = functions.begin(); it != functions.end(); ++it)
        {
            (*it)();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    P p;
    p.call();
}
```

---

After further clarification from the OP I'll propose this:

```
class P
{
    typedef std::function<void (void)> func_t;
    std::map<const char*, func_t> functions;
public:
    P()
    {
        functions["foo1"] = std::bind(&P::foo1, this);
        functions["foo2"] = std::bind(&P::foo2, this);
        functions["foo3"] = std::bind(&P::foo3, this);
    }
    void foo1(void)
    {
        std::cout << "foo1\n";
    }
    void foo2(void)
    {
        std::cout << "foo2\n";
    }
    void foo3(void)
    {
        std::cout << "foo3\n";
    }
    void call_by_name(const char* func_name)
    {
        functions[func_name]();
    }
};

int main()
{
    P p;
    p.call_by_name("foo1");
    p.call_by_name("foo2");
    p.call_by_name("foo3");
}
```

Comment: I wasn't going to mention `std::bind`, but you explained it pretty well :)

Comment: @Peter R
I'm trying to compare a vector of strings in a method, then call an identically named method in `MyClass.ccp`, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Hobbyist, If you mean something like reflection, apart from some reflection libraries out there, a map of strings to functions is probably the easiest you can do, and even then, it's hard to include different signatures. And speak of that, it's exactly what Peter has done in his answer now :)

Comment: @chris
I have no idea what reflection is, I just thought it was logical and straightforward to do, I was going to use a map but thought that asking the question about using a vector would be much clearer, I'll edit it for a map once I fully understand how it works!

Comment: @Hobbyist, Put simply, reflection would allow you to link strings containing the names of classes and functions with the actual classes and functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use member function pointers like this (the C++11 is unrelated to that part):

```
struct S {
   int foo(){std::cout<<"foo"; return 0;}
   int bar(){std::cout<<"bar"; return 0;}
};

int main() {
   std::vector<int(S::*)()> funcs{&S::foo, &S::bar};

   S s;
   for (auto func : funcs) {
      (s.*func)();
   }
}
```

However, if you use C++11, `std::function` can make it a bit cleaner:

```
std::vector<std::function<int(S &)>> funcs{&S::foo, &S::bar};

S s;
for (auto func : funcs) {
   func(s);
}
```

If you use C++03, Boost has `boost::function`, which is similar.

Comment: I think I might have gotten the terminology wrong too =s are methods and functions the same thing? EG; `void MyClass::myMethod() { } ;` in `MyClass.ccp`

Comment: @Hobbyist, Yes, they are. They're tended to be called functions in C++. That specifically is a member function. Something like Java wouldn't have need for "member function", since every function must be in a class in Java, so all member functions in Java are typically called methods.